# Find the matrix A that satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix A that satisfies the equation

$$
\left[
2\left[
\begin{array}{}
  1&1\\
  -2&3
\end{array}
\right] -5A^{-1}
\right]
^T= 
\left(4A^T
\right)^{-1}$$

I'm not sure how to start solving this question. where/how do i start and how do i think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the given matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}=B$$ and call $(A^T)^{-1}=C=(A^{-1})^T$, then we have $$(2B^T-5(A^{-1})^T)=(4A^T)^{-1} \implies 2B^T-5C= \frac{1}{4}C\implies B^T=\frac{21}{8} C \implies (B^T)^T=\frac{21}{8} C^T=\frac{21}{8} A^{-1} \implies B=\frac{21}{8} A^{-1} \implies A= \frac{21}{8}B^{-1}$$

$$\implies A=\frac{21}{40}\begin{pmatrix} 3 &-1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Here we have used the interchangeability of transpose and inverse.

Comment: why did you set (2B^T-5(A^{-1})^T)=0  and not =(4A^T)^-1?

Comment: @ELZP Sorry, I may have read the question wrong. Now I have corrected it. Thanks for the alert.

Comment: Ahh i see, now i understand, thank you

Comment: shouldnt the answe 21/8(B)^-1? how did you get 21/40

Comment: @ELZP $1/5$ is common in $B^{-1}$, $B^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 3/5 &-1/5 \\ 2/5 & 1/5 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: forgot about the inverse, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove parentheses by using the properties of the inverse, transpose, and matrix multiplication.
$$
\left[
2\pmatrix{ 1&1\\-2&3} -5A^{-1}
\right] ^T = 
\left(4A^T
\right)^{-1}\\
2\pmatrix{ 1&1\\-2&3}^T -5(A^{-1})^T = 
\frac 14 \left(A^T
\right)^{-1}\\
2\pmatrix{ 1&1\\-2&3}^T -5(A^{-1})^T = 
\frac 14 \left(A^{-1}
\right)^{T}.
$$
Once you have solved this last equation for $A^{-1}$, you can find $A$.